# Как передать объект с данными из оформленной подписки subscribe

Tags: angular

Есть функция getUser в сервисе UserDataService, в которой я вызываю функцию tokens, получаю token и передаю его другой функции getUser, от куда я получаю пользователя по его id.

```
  getUser(id: number) {
    return this.sharedDataService.tokens.subscribe(
      result=> {
        return this.userService.getUser(result, id).subscribe(
          (resultService: DataResponse<User>) => {
            if (resultService.status === StatusType.SUCCESSFUL) {
              return resultService.data;
            } else {
              return null;
            }
          });
      });
  }
```

Как мне получить объект User при вызове этой функции?
Такой код работать не будет.

```
let user = this.userDataService.getUser(1);
```

Как правильно передавать объекты из таких функций?
Можно передавать по событию, но в данном случае это не очень удобно.
Может можно оформить подписку на функцию getUser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы использовать последовательные запросы стоит использовать операторы RXJS, например switchMap. Почитать подробнее можно [тут](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/switchMap) и [тут](http://coldfox.ru/article/5d4b28a0c076ee44b59a1736/RxJS-map-mergeMap-switchMap-concatMap)

```js
getUser$(id: number): Observable < /*тут нужно указать тип*/ > | null {
    return this.sharedDataService.tokens
        .pipe(
            switchMap(result => this.userService.getUser(result, id)), 
            map((resultService: DataResponse < User > ) => resultService.status === StatusType.SUCCESSFUL ? resultService.data : null)
        )
    };

    this.getUser$(1).subscribe((data) => {
      if (data) { //проверка что не null
        ...
      }
    })
```